# Saving to keychain broken in iOS 9: errSecNoAccessForItem -25243

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keychain

What I have is working on < iOS 9.

In my keychain wrapper's insertValue method, SecItemAdd returns -25243 which I believe is the error errSecNoAccessForItem

```
OSStatus status =   SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(dictionary), NULL);
```

keychain-access-groups is set with $(AppIdentifierPrefix)my-suite

Keychain Sharing is turned on with the keychain group: my-suite

What has changed in iOS 9?